# animate div moving from one place to another

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I am designing a potal framework and I have multiple portlets(divs) within the main div.
When I move a div, I want it to move to the top of the page and expand vertically.  **All of this works, however, I would like to animate the moving part.**

this is what my code looks like

```
$('#smallpotletdiv').prependTo($('#maindiv'));
```

what would someone that knows more about animation suggest? How would I show the div moving from its current location and attach itself to the new location?

Comment: its something like this: http://dropthings.omaralzabir.com/  each window hosts its own application.  if you notice this person is also moving up the div when you click on the arrow next to the "edit" button on a widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play with the positions using animate and prepend at last. After the prepend is complete, change the values to default

```
$("#smallpotletdiv").animate({
      top: 300,
      left: 500     
}).prependTo($("#maindiv")).css({
      top: 'auto',
      left: 'auto'
});
```

#### Update:

You working codes will look something like this

```
current.animate({
  top: -30,
  left: -20     
}, 2000, function() {
    current.prependTo(prependToDiv).css({
       top: 'auto',
       left: 'auto'
    });        
});
```

#### [Check Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4Bgx7/372/)

The problem with their execution were that, you didn't position the element to be movable through left and top. For that an element has to be positioned absolutely i.e. `position: absolute`.

Comment: thats not working, i dont see any effects on the screen. I dont know what I am doing wrong. (thanks for the response btw)

Comment: @VijayV, Do you have a demo i can play with?

Comment: ok, let me see if i can give you a stripped down working demo.

Comment: Here you go. Please let me know if this works: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/4Bgx7/368/

Comment: @Stax - Any luck with my problem yet ?

Comment: Oops didnt see your update.  Thank you very much. Let me try that let you know.  Again I appreciate your help!

Comment: This worked. thanks a lot for your help.  Unfortunately I dont have enough reps to mark this the answer.

Comment: @VijayV, You might not be able to vote, but you can accept an answer. Just click on the check sign at the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
  $('#smallpotletdiv').animate
```

You can use it's parameters: for ex

```
width: ['toggle', 'swing'],
    height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
    opacity: 'toggle'
```

[JQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: thanks for the fast response, but shouldnt the animate me added to the prependTo call?  I am confused sorry.

Comment: Yes..it should be added to prependTo call

Comment: ok i dont know what i am doing wrong, i followed the example on the jQuery website.  .prependTo('#mainDiv').animate({ width: '100%'},{ queue: false, duration: 3000 }); and its not working.  I guess the bigger problem is, I dont know what kind of effect will make the move look nice

Comment: Exactly..its up to you to select

Answer (score 0):

One cool tool for implementing this is a ReactJS tool called react-magic-move
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-magic-move

This has the potential to manipulate the DOM to change where an element is located in a smooth way. It is however, not very easy to implement as it is not being supported and using out of date version of ReactJS.

See the demo here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5e7kWSHWTg#t=424